# Non nullable type throwing KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, nullpointerexception

I have the following class in java

```
public class MyZClass1_ {

    public int x = 100;

}
```

and that test in kotlin

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class _01_SO_KotlinReflectionAccessorReturnTypeKotlinNull {

    @Test
    fun demonstrate_returnTypeReflectionOfAccessorFunctionInJavaClassThrowsKotlinNull() {
        val zClass1_ = MyZClass1_::class
        for (declaredProperty in zClass1_.declaredMemberProperties) {
            val propertyGetter = declaredProperty.getter
            assertNotNull(propertyGetter)
            try {
                val returnType = propertyGetter.returnType
            } catch (ex: KotlinNullPointerException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- `propertyGetter` is not null (as asserted)
- `propertyGetter.returnType` has a non-nullable type `KType`
- The problem is that the line `val returnType = propertyGetter.returnType` throws a `KotlinNullPointerException`.
- Why is that? Am i missing something?

Comment: What is the value of propertyGetter in the debugger?

Comment: `println(propertyGetter.property)` prints `var z_others.MyZClass1_.x: kotlin.Int`